# Need help on excel autocomplete function for drop-down list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I'm trying to add an auto-complete function to some of the boxes on the first sheet that I have for entering data on an excel worksheet, but I can't figure out how so. Here's the link for the excel document. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ksoDGxry1tR2JGNnhoSEZuYU0/view?usp=sharing

I have read some of the articles here but I didn't really get how to apply them to my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very handy guide for doing just that, but **you need to rely on a mixture of VBA and form controls**, specifically comboboxes. The initial method was outlined in a slightly revamped [guide by Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html).

This guide was later expanded into, what I felt, was a slightly easier and more robust method dubbed ["the magical floating activeX control".](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12362/The-magical-floating-ActiveX-control.html)

I hope you have luck with those two - but knowledge of VBA will help you get the most out of it. You have to customize their setup to match your data structures. I use this method to produce 'autocomplete' forms for users in my organization. So far, my one extension has been to make an 'on/off' button for this code, because it's method runs *constantly*, meaning that you lose the ability to do UNDO in excel while the lookup/autocomplete code is available to the user. I strongly advise setting up a button/feature that allows a user to disable it when not in use.

For enable/disable, here is the very-rough code that will do the job to ensure the code doesn't execute when you don't want it to. This disables the 'catch' that watches for the intial value change in the script from the links above.

```
   If Application.EnableEvents = False Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    btn_Enable.ForeColor = 0
Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    btn_Enable.ForeColor = 35653
End If
```